# Extending coboundary to cocycle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

I was reading [these notes](https://www0.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2015/3111/26/AlgebraicTopologyNotes.pdf) and got confused at the beginning of section 9.2 (p. 21-22).

$i^n$ is the map from $Z^n$ (i.e. ($\ker\partial^n$))to $B^n$ (i.e. $\text{im}(\partial^{n-1})$) of a cochain complex

$$...\to C^n\xrightarrow{\partial^n}C^{n+1}\xrightarrow{\partial^{n+1}}C^{n+2}\to ...$$

From the long exact sequence in homology

$$...\to Z^{n-1}\xrightarrow{i^{n-1}} B^{n-1}\to H^n(C_{\bullet})\to Z^n\xrightarrow{i^{n}} ...$$

we get the short exact sequence

$$0\to \text{coker}(i^{n-1})\to B^{n-1}\to H^n(C_{\bullet})\to \ker(i^n)\to 0$$

Thus far, is absolutely clear.

> If we are working over a field and assuming that $H^n(C_{\bullet})$ is finite dimensional, $\text{coker}(i^{n-1}) = 0$ as every $f \in B^{n−1}$
>   can be extended to $\tilde{f}\in Z^{n−1}$.

This, on the other hand, is completely unclear to me.

As far as I understand, elements of $B^{n-1}$ are elements of $\text{im}(\partial^{n-2})$, that is, maps $f$ of the form

$$\text{im}(f:C_{n-1}\xrightarrow{\partial_{n-1}}C_{n-2}\xrightarrow{\sigma}G)$$

while those in $Z^{n-1}$ are of the form

$$\ker(\tilde{f}:C_{n}\xrightarrow{\partial_{n}}C_{n-1}\xrightarrow{\sigma}G)$$

What does it mean to extend $f$ to $\tilde{f}$, and why do we need $H^n(C_{\bullet})$ to be finite-dimensional?

Comment: $i^n$ should map from $Z^n$ to $B^n$. Got that the wrong way round in my first sentence

Comment: The claim does not make a lot of sense. In what way elements of $B^{n-1}$, which are simpy elements of an abelian group, be «extended» to $Z^{n-1}$?

Comment: I don't know, it's what it says in these (public domain) lecture notes, on page 22 (just before thm 9.5) https://www0.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2015/3111/26/AlgebraicTopologyNotes.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion stems from the fact that you are using the wrong definition of $Z^n$ and $B^n$.  They are *not* defined to be $\ker(\partial^n)$ and $\operatorname{im}(\partial^{n-1})$.  Rather, they are defined to be the duals of $Z_n$ and $B_n$; that is, $Z^n=\operatorname{Hom}(Z_n,G)$ and $B^n=\operatorname{Hom}(B_n,G)$.  The map $i^n$ is then the map that takes an element of $Z^n$ and restricts it to the subgroup $B_n$ of $Z_n$ to get an element of $B^n$.  So to show that $i^n$ is surjective, it does make sense to talk about extending elements of $B^n$ to elements of $Z^n$: you are taking a homomorphism $B_n\to G$ and trying to extend it to a homomorphism $Z_n\to G$.  If you are working with vector spaces, this is always possible: a linear map on a subspace of a vector space always extends to the entire vector space (since you can take a basis for the subspace and extend it to a basis for the entire space).

(The assumption that $H^n(C_\bullet)$ is finite-dimensional is totally irrelevant, and I don't know why they mentioned it.)

Comment: "They are _not_ defined to be $\ker(\partial^n)$ and $\operatorname{im}(\partial^{n-1})$"

but isn't that what they are defined to be at the top of page 20?

Comment: Oof...they are.  But in section 9.2, they start using them with a different meaning, without explicitly mentioning that they are doing so.  These seem like not the most cleanly-written notes...

Comment: Ok, so we have an abelian group over a field, we can regard it as a vector space?

Thank you very much for your time and your clear answer

Comment: Er, when it talks about working "over a field", it really means "replace the word 'abelian group' with 'vector space over $k$' in everything we have said", for some fixed field $k$.  So you assume that you actually had a chain complex of vector spaces and linear maps, and $G$ is also a vector space, and $\operatorname{Hom}(C,G)$ refers to the space of linear maps, and so on.

Comment: Oh ok. That makes a lot more sense, as otherwise there would've been part of the structure missing.

Comment: I would warn you more generally that these notes appear to quite literally be "lecture notes": they are intended to be used by the author when lecturing, rather than read by a wider audience.  So there are a lot of things left out that the author understands and knows to say when lecturing, but are not necessarily clear to someone else (like you) trying to read the notes.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I'll stick to Hatcher then